# css right bar menu and content moving down

Tags: html, css

I have created a right menu bar with css and hml. It is appearing like this:

[image]

And when small screen is like this:

[image]

1. I don't want this. My working [code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/w0y5m71v/5/).
2. I want a scroll bar y and 100% height.

   ```
   <div id="1map">
       <div class="rightcontainer">
           <div class="menubox">
               <div class="item">Menu-1</div>
               <div class="item">Menu-2</div>
               <div class="item">Menu-3</div>
           </div>
           <div class="mainbox">
               <div class="panel panel-success">
                   <div class="panel-heading">Products</div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <ul class="list-group">
                           <li class="list-group-item">Toshiba Notebook</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Asus Notebook</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Prod-4</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Prod-5</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Prod-6</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Prod-7</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel panel-primary">
                   <div class="panel-heading">Toshiba Details</div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <ul class="list-group">
                           <li class="list-group-item">Hdd 200GB</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">Ram 8GB DDR5</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item">CPU i7</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel panel-info">
                   <div class="panel-heading">Images</div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <img src=".." alt="..." class="img-rounded">
                       <img src=".." alt="..." class="img-rounded">
                       <img src=".." alt="..." class="img-rounded">
                       <img src=".." alt="..." class="img-rounded">
                   </div>
               </div>                  
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: sorry it is not clear for me what is the final result,... do you want menubox kept on the left of mainbox even on smaller screen?

Comment: I want that should appear like first image. But menu content is moving down when smaller borser width like second image .

Comment: You can just add min-width:400px to .rightcontainer: http://jsfiddle.net/w0y5m71v/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mainbox { float: none; }
```

:)

**UPDATE** : http://jsfiddle.net/agttL00f/

It hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I am new at css :) But I wonder why none? I have main rightcontainer and two container in it. So I think this two container should be float left.

Comment: Im not sure, really. Sometimes with css is a matter of intuition. When you put float left to an element, it tries to positionate so left as possible. (If you want, mark my answer as accepted :))